# Regulating 12.8 V, 240 W from a LiFePO4 to 12 V for computer

Tags: voltage-regulator, lifepo4

I have a  LiFePO4 12.8 V, 20 Ah capable of 244 watts. I am trying to power a computer that needs regulated 12 V that will need 200 W. The regulators I find on Amazon don't cut it. The ones that handle the power needed are of 24 V input and the ones that are of adjustable input/output voltage cannot handle the 200 W power. Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

I also don't want to put two batteries in series to get the 24 V of some of those regulators for reasons of portability of the batteries. (I plan to travel with the batteries so I will later put 3 × 100 W in parallel.)

More info on computer: it is a built computer using the PSU found link below. It says input is of range Input voltage: +12V/DC(11.4-12.6V). te battery is 13.4V when fully charged.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PPYWGNH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PPYWGNH)
RGEEK 24pin DC ATX PSU 12V DC Input 250W Peak Output Switch DC-DC ATX Pico PSU Mini ITX PC Power

Comment: If the PC takes 12V it is highly likely it will work with the unregulated 12V-14.4V from the battery. If this is the case, maybe you don't need a regulator.

Comment: If you want portability, use a computer that requires much less than 200W. Your battery will be lucky to last 30 minutes.

Comment: @Finbarr the 20Ah battery should last for a few hours. the computer will be on average 80W running.

Comment: @bobflux I was thinking the same but I'm too nervous to test this. there are some expensive parts in there I don't want to damage.

Comment: Where do you get the "regulated 12.05V" specification? It seems unreasonably precise.

Comment: @brhans That's just the voltage I measured when using the power adapter to power the computer from the AC outlet. I'm sure it doesn't need to be exactly this.

Comment: To find out what is the input voltage range of the computer, please state the make and model and preferably link to such a computer to find manuals etc.

Comment: Does this computer have any kind of data or specification which shows what it really needs?

Comment: @brhans I edited the post and put details of the PSU used for the computer.

Comment: I have a feeling this board passes through the 12V input unregulated to the 12V rail. So you might want to check what the components downstream can accept.

Comment: Oh yes the internal 12V rail is most likely straight from the 12V input. Since no component in the PC actually uses 12V, it's all buck switching converters to generate all the low voltages...

Comment: Brute force - Use a BMF diode (big mother ...)   Such as https://www.vishay.com/docs/94709/vst20hf220.pdf $$$$  This will drop about 0.7-1.0V at your current levels.  It'll get pretty warm.   Wasteful of power but it would work.

Comment: you could very well build a charger/regulator you will only need 4 ics and some auxiliary components if you want a simple version (if you can actually source the components you need that is)

Answer (score 1):

If you're *serious* about wanting a whopping 200W, the [M4-ATX-HV from mini-box](https://www.mini-box.com/M4-ATX-HV?sc=8&category=981) (the US Pico-PSU distributor) claims to do it.  They've also got a variety of smaller options including some lower powered LiFePO4 UPS gadgets.

Realize that 200W means you need to be prepared for **17A sustained current** in all of your 12V wiring.  Both inside and outside the batteries.  That's a LOT... you need wide gauge wires and heavy duty connectors and battery packs designed for such a high discharge rate.

Comment: Also, re: _"I plan to travel with the batteries"_... if you intend air travel, look up restrictions on battery capacities and quantities you are allowed to carry anywhere you might go. It doesn't matter if LiFePO4 is "safe", security theater agents won't care.